# /boot full. Updates can't install. Can I delete things?

Tags: boot

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

I can't install the latest updates and the error it's giving me is that /boot is full.

Looking in /boot, I see a lot of the following files:

```
initrd.img-4.4.0-**xx**-generic

vmlinuz-4.4.0-**xx**-generic

vmlinuz-4.4.0-**xx**-generic.efi.signed

config-4.4.0-**xx**-generic

abi-4.4.0-**xx**-generic

System.map-4.4.0-**xx**-generic


**xx** varies from 21 to 38...
```

Can I and should I delete anything that's not the latest?

Comment: May I ask why /boot is so small? Is it a separate partition or does the whole system does lack space?

Comment: It's what the system created when I installed.

Answer (score 2):

Running `apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-**xx**-generic` may help. Deleting by hand may cause some unexpected issues as you have no experience before. The `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file contains the bootup menu list which may call the image you just deleted.